# Extract option values from 'drop down menu' using Selenium/Beautiful Soup- Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to extract year, car model and car data from the following link:
https://auto-buy.geico.com/nb#/sale/vehicle/gskmsi/

Following is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
chromedriver = "D:\Codes\Webscraping\chromedriver.exe"



driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)

try:
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)
    driver.get('https://auto-buy.geico.com/nb#/sale/vehicle/gskmsi/')
    select_element = ui.Select(ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "vehicleYear"))))
    select_element.select_by_visible_text("2017")
    time.sleep(5)
    select_element = ui.Select(ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "vehicleMake"))))
    select_element.select_by_visible_text("Acura")
    time.sleep(5)
    select_element = ui.Select(ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "vehicleModel"))))
    select_element.select_by_visible_text("ILX")
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='vehicleMake']"):
        print (i.get_attribute("value"))
    select_box = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='vehicleMake']"))
    # get all options
    options = select_box.options
    print(options)    
except TimeoutException as ex:
    isrunning = 0
    print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(ex))
    driver.close()
```

Note: While running the code, first customer information page will be loaded which you can fill randomly with zip 75002

My problem comes in how do i extract all the values for year, car model and car make from the site now? Does selenium help in that? Or do i use Beautiful Soup now? Any code related help will be great.

Edit: I don't have any error in code as such. I just don't know the code for extracting values of year, car model and car make
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Do you see any error? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest issue is that Make is only populated once Year is selected. Model is only populated once Year is selected. You are going to have to iterate through each drop down to retrieve all values. I won't provide the entire code, but it should be pretty simple. First start by getting the Year dropdown and it's values

```
year_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="vehicleYear"]')
years = [year.text for year in year_dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')]
```

you're going to get a blank value as the first item in this list, because the first item in the dropdown is blank. you have options on removing it:

```
years = years[1:]
```

or, a somewhat safer method:

```
years = [year for year in years if year]
```

this method will only keep values in the list that aren't empty.

for you are going to have to iterate through the year drop down:

```
for year in years:
    year_dropdown.find_element_by_xpath('.//option[text()="%s"]' % year).click()
```

in that `for` loop, you are going to have to now do the same exact thing, but for the make:

```
make_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="vehicleMake"]')
makes = [make.text for year in year_dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')]
```

see where we're going with this? you're now repeating the same code as you did for the Year dropdown, but for the Make. and you will do the same thing for the Model. your flow will end up being like:

```
for year in years:
    for make in makes:
        for model in models:
           ...
```

what we don't know, however, is what you plan on doing with the extracted data, so i can't help you with the output. but this is how you can extract the data. please note that every `for` loops iteration will overwrite it's child list. so `makes` will be overwritten after a year has been iterated over, and each `models` will be overwritten after a make has been iterated over.